# Is it possible to input new html elements under the Elements tab in inspect element on a webpage using Python, Javascript or Java?

Tags: javascript, python, html, browser

I have a large table to enter a large set of text into on a webpage. I'm looking to automate this task.
The elements in the table are all under a

```
<div class=Identifier> </div>
```

when viewing inspect element.

I want to take my data set, and input it under the div like so

```
<div class=Identifier> 
  <p>Text to enter</p>
</div>
```

Is this possible in Python, Javascript or Java and how should I be going about this?

Comment: The simplest and most basic way (in JavaScript) to assign HTML content is to call `innerHTML` e.g. `document.querySelector('.indentifier').innerHTML = '<p>Text to enter</p>';`, but you should create the paragraph element, assign a text value, and then append it to the designated element. Java and Python are server languages, so they will not be able to manipulate the client. Only JavaScript will be able to change the content client-side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript is to get the element with a query selector then add to the innerHTML.

```
const yourDiv = document.querySelector(".Identifier");
const text = "Text to enter"

yourDiv.innerHTML = `<p>${text}</p>`
```